# How to design a REST service to response with different levels of information?

Tags: spring, rest, api-design

I would like to have a single service that can respond with different levels of information:

Level 1:

```
{
    "field_1": "value_1",
    "field_2": "value_2"
}
```

Level 2:

```
{
    "field_1": "value_1",
    "field_2": "value_2",
    "field_3": "value_3"
}
```

Level 3:

```
{
    "field_1": "value_1",
    "field_2": "value_2",
    "field_3": "value_3",
    "field_4": "value_4"
}
```

My first approach is using a parameter in the request such like this:

```
@RestController
public <ResponseObject> getInfo(..., @RequestParam levelInfo) {
    service.getInfo(..., levelInfo);
}

@Service
public <ResponseObject> getInfo(..., levelInfo) {
    if (levelInfo == 1)
        return setupResponseLevel1();
    if (levelInfo == 2)
        return setupResponseLevel1();
    if (levelInfo == 3)
        return setupResponseLevel1();
}
private <ResponseObject> setupResponseLevel1() {
    responseObject.setField_1(repository.getField1());
    responseObject.setField_2(repository.getField2());
    return responseObject;
}
private <ResponseObject> setupResponseLevel2() {
    responseObject = this.setupResponseLevel1();
    responseObject.setField_3(repository.getField3());
    return responseObject;
}
private <ResponseObject> setupResponseLevel3() {
    responseObject = this.setupResponseLevel2();
    responseObject.setField_4(repository.getField4());
    return responseObject;
}

@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
public class ResponseObject {
    private String field_1;
    private String field_2;
    private String field_3;
    private String field_4;

    // Getters & setters...
}
```

My API will be very large and I need to find a pattern that I can reuse in many services.

Do you know any cleaner way to do it?

**EDIT**: I'm sorry, I did not explain with the properly precision.

I like the ideas of the answers but I have added more code to the `@Service` so that you understand that the problem is not only the presentation of the response (JSON) but also the saving of the cost of obtaining the information (queries to BBDD).

Comment: you can write a custom serializer and control what you return

Comment: That's where [GraphQL](http://graphql.org/) comes in!

Comment: Take at look at Spring Data REST [projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts.projections)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `@JsonView` annotation for that. A simple example would look like this

```
public class Views {
    public static class LevelOne {
    }

    public static class LevelTwo extends LevelOne {
    }
}


public class ResponseObject {

    @JsonView(Views.LevelOne.class)
    private String field_1;

    @JsonView(Views.LevelOne.class)
    private String field_2;

    @JsonView(Views.LevelTwo.class)
    private String field_3;

}
```

and method for serializing

```
public String toJson(Class<?> view) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    return objectMapper.writerWithView(view).writeValueAsString(this);
}
```

if the `toJson` method is called with `Views.LevelOne.class` as an argument, only the field_1 and field_2 will be serialized. If it is called with `Views.LevelTwo.class`, all three fields would be serialized.

You can choose which view to use based on parameter as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

What about a URL scheme along the lines of:

```
https://your.api/info/2
```

then

```
@RequestMapping("/info/{levelInfo}")
public <ResponseObject> getInfo(..., @PathVariable String levelInfo) {
```

where 2 is the level. As the level is part of your domain, i.e. it has relevance to your clients, you could capture that in the database with a level column for each field, 1,2,3,4 etc then use the repository to:

```
repository.findByLevelLessThanEqual(levelInfo)
```

which could return a package of information containing all the required fields. So if you ask for level 1, you only get level 1 fields. If you ask for level 4, you get all fields up to and including level 4

[Spring JPA LessThanEqual documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/)